# simple XHR file upload doesn't transmit files

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

The upload.php script's `$_FILES` variable stays zero length. Why is the file not sent? Everything seems to be in order though. I would like to remove the form and perform the upload entirely through the `onchange` handler. Is this possible?

```
<li>upload:<form id=upload enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file id=file name=o onchange="submit()"/>
</form></li>

<script>
document.getElementById('upload').submit=function(){
var ul=document.getElementById('file');
if(ul.files.length>0){
  file=ul.files[0];
  var x=(window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
    alert(x.responseText);}
  }
  x.open('post','upload.php',true);
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
  x.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.name);
  x.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.size);
  x.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.type);
  x.send(file);
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: What are those `upload` and `submit` functions?

Comment: You want to use `.onsubmit`!

Comment: `onSubmit` and `submit` are the same, I haven't looked at browser compatibilty yet

Comment: Well, they are not, which might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Changing to onSubmit produces the exact same results: form is sent asynchonously but $_FILES array is empty. Haven't found any documentation about the difference so far, but the issue seems to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FormData](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/#the-formdata-interface), it sets the headers on its own.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Filedata", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);

var x=(window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
   alert(x.responseText);}
}
x.open("POST", url);
x.send(formData);
```